# INFORMS template flattens out my algorithms

Tags: algorithm2e

I am preparing a manuscript using the INFORMS style files, which can be downloaded here: https://pubsonline.informs.org/authorportal/latex-style-files

(That page doesn't mention a license, so I don't know if I am allowed to reproduce the contents of the `.sty` file here.)

When I add an algorithm with `algorithm2e` to this template, something overrides the default indendation and I get a flat margin on the left. Here is a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{informs1}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
$y \gets 0$\;
\For{$x \in X$}{
    $y \gets y + x$\;
}
\Return{$y$}\;
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

and the output:

[image]

The third line should be indented, and have no strange vertical rule on the left.

**How do I prevent this template from flattening my `algorithm2e` algorithms/**

Comment: Please tell us which of the linked files exactly contains the document class you used.

Comment: For the purposes of this question, the files are identical. They all include the file `informs1.sty` or `informs3.sty` which is what causes the problem. They differ only in that the same `.tex` file contains a bunch of header information.

Comment: I see ... well, I found it anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful when adding packages to journal templates, as they might not support it. I could not find the actual reason why this happens in the code, but obviously, the document class sets the skip values for indentation of algorithms to zero.

In order to restore the default indentation defined by the `algorithm2e` package, you can add `\SetInd{.5em}{1em}` directly before `\begin{algorithm}`. So simplify things, I would probably define a new environment:

```
\documentclass{informs1}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\newenvironment{nalgorithm}{
\begingroup
\SetInd{.5em}{1em}
\begin{algorithm}%
}{%
\end{algorithm}
\endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{nalgorithm}
$y \gets 0$\;
\For{$x \in X$}{
    $y \gets y + x$\;
}
\Return{$y$}\;
\end{nalgorithm}

\end{document}
```

---

If you want to keep the code base, you could make use of the `etoolbox` package and inject the needed line of code. However, this would mean that you even load two packages to the document class:

```
\documentclass{informs1}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithm}{\SetInd{.5em}{1em}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
$y \gets 0$\;
\For{$x \in X$}{
    $y \gets y + x$\;
}
\Return{$y$}\;
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to do this that won't require me to replace all the instances of `algorithm` in my document? I'm trying to maintain a `body.tex` file that I can input to various templates. I tried using `\let\loweredalgorithm\algorithm` and then `\renewenvironment{algorithm}...` with your code but it gives me a `\begin{lrbox} on input line 134 ended by \end{loweredalgorithm}` error.

Answer (score 3):

Just restore the desired indentations.

```
\documentclass{informs1}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\SetInd{5pt}{10pt}
\SetNlSty{relax}{}{\enspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
$y \gets 0$\;
\For{$x \in X$}{
    $y \gets y + x$\;
}
\Return{$y$}\;
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Duh! This did not work when I tried. This is obviously much easier than my approach.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason, this approach gets me different (too small) spacing when I set it to the ostensible default of `\SetInd{0.5em}{1em}`. Seems like another quirk of the template. Of course, I can work around it by doing font size math and using `\SetInd{_pt}{__pt}`.